Hair particle emitter not obeying rotation?

I'm sort of a novice at Blender, but I'm pretty sure that if I want this hair to all stand up straight I should be using the rotation tab and adjusting the Orientation Axis? Doing so hasn't been helping (the grass continues to stand at an angle based on the plane beneath it). Does anyone have any advice perhaps?
